# How to visualize the stack fame for this Binary Tree Insertion?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

How to visualize the stack fame for this Binary Tree Insertion ? This is very important as this is recursive in nature. Once I understood recursion i was able to write recursive solutions. Here i understand the concept how its working recursively, but not fully understood how the stackframe looks ... For Example the
[image]

This is how we can visualize the recursive sum, is there any way to do it for the Binary Tree Insertion ?

This is the code:
[image]

Comment: The stack frame for `insertItem()` contains the return address, the parameters, and the local variables, and maybe a pushed base pointer from the calling stack frame. Your diagram is not of a stack frame, although it might have something to do with the call *stack.*

Comment: @user207421 right, my mistake, but can we represent call stack something like that for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a diagram which can help in understanding the elements and mentally things how the stacks are framed.

Suppose we are adding 5,3,2 :
This is how we can visualize mentally:

[image]

Please refer to this code for understanding...

```
private BTNode insert(BTNode node, int key, String value) {


//If node is null, set the new node as it is...
if (node == null) {

    //create the new node to be inserted and set it
    node = new BTNode(key, value);

    return node;
}

// Else walk till the node has key < that node's key
if (key < node.key) {
    node.left = insert(node.left, key, value);
}

// Else walk till the node has key > that node's key
if (key > node.key) {
    node.right = insert(node.right, key, value);
}

return node;
}
```